# I can't get hold of LPRECT structure data, what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: c++, winapi

It should be working without issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  HWND consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
  LPRECT lpRect;
  GetWindowRect(consoleWindow,lpRect);
  cout << lpRect.top <<endl;
}
```

but instead I get this:

```
error: request for member 'top' in 'lpRect', which is of non-class type 'LPRECT {aka tagRECT*}'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is wrong. Windows expects a valid Rect here. LPRECT is just a pointer and you haven't initialized it. Please modify it like this.

```
HWND consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
RECT aRect;
GetWindowRect(consoleWindow,&aRect);
cout << aRect.top <<endl;
```

Comment: Doesn't `GetWindowRect` initialize it?

Comment: no... it doesn't.. unfortunately the MSDN documentation is vague on this. Please see their example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644996(v=vs.85).aspx#init_box

Comment: @Luchian: How could a C function change a pointer in the caller?  It can only write into the buffer whose address is passed.

Comment: @Luchian: The entire Windows API uses C-compatible function signatures.  Nothing else is even close to as portable (across compilers, different languages).

Answer (score 5):

The `LPRECT` type is a *pointer* to `RECT`. This is (unfortunately, in my opinion) common in the Win32 API, that they play "hide the asterisk" on you. It makes for more confusion, since the asterisk is important in C.

So, anyway, you need to use an actual `RECT` to have somewhere to store the result:

```
RECT rect; /* An actual RECT, with space for holding a rectangle. */

/* The type of &rect is LPRECT. */
GetWindowRect(consoleWindow, &rect);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
RECT Rect;
GetWindowRect(consoleWindow, &Rect);
cout << Rect.top <<endl;
```

I would say you are a C# guy because you attempted to use the types and API call without understanding of pointers. `LPRECT` is a derived type which says it is a pointer to `RECT`. Having a variable of this type, you declared a pointer to nothing, to invalid memory address (the pointer variable is left uninitialized). Your code would expectedly crash the app.

You need to hold a `RECT` variable instead, and pass a pointer to it to have it initialized/filed by the API.

Comment: Well I'd say the explanation was good enough for the fullness of origanal question, but you are right it's worth explaining for others hitting this question.