# How to use GetWindowRect

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Consider the following code:

```
LPRECT lpRect;
GetWindowRect(hwnd, lpRect);
```

I don't know how to get information from `lpRect`; please advise.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851278/i-cant-get-hold-of-lprect-structure-data-what-im-doing-wrong

Comment: Do you not know how to use a structure? LPRECT is just a pointer to a RECT structure, so something like lpRect->x would access a member of it.

Comment: oh my gosh wow im gonna delete this question now k? k.

Comment: and damon so yeah i just started coding in general, and i wasn't sure.

Comment: well now that its answered im not gonna delete it, and goodgood michael that is the answer.

Comment: If you want to accept an answer you should probably go with [datenwolf's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18291845/1889329) submission. Michael's answer does not really address your problem (writing to random memory).

Comment: @GingerJack: I rolled back your edit, which was inappropriate for the following reasons: (1) it introduced a brand new bug -- wrong size passed to `malloc()` (2) it conflicted with existing answers (3) code in questions should only be edited to improve forwarding, never to fix a bug, because the bugs are an important part of the question.  Even when a question contains unrelated code or problems outside the question being asked, cleanup/reduction to MCVE should be done only in answers.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What you wrote is wrong. The Windows API uses a hideous variable and type naming convention. `LPRECT` means "Long Pointer to Rect", which on your usual architecture is just a `RECT*`. What you wrote is some uninitialized pointer variable, pointing at some arbitrary location (if you're unlucky something that when modified will crash your program).

This is what you actually require:

```
RECT rect;
GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);
```

RECT itself is a structure

```
typedef struct _RECT {
  LONG left;
  LONG top;
  LONG right;
  LONG bottom;
} RECT;
```

Comment: tho u super pro I didn't try it at first, then I learned the hard way. (I got "unlucky")

Comment: I use a laptop and the external display. All set 1920x1080 resolution. If I run my Delphi 7 program in the primray screen I get different RECTANGLE values like I run my program on the secondary display. [Pictures from source code](https://mega.nz/folder/Z5oREQxY#pgkh-jr7SbZ68E7UxAxZkw)

Comment: @Lionking: Maybe effected by HiDPI scaling. Check if UI scaling is set to a value other than 100%. If so, set to 100% and retry if it works then. If that's the case you'll have to take that scaling into account, too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows

Answer (score 2):

You can get the coordinates of the window :

```
lpRect->left
lpRect->right
lpRect->top
lpRect->bottom
```

More information here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162897(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: just so you know I liked yours better :O

Comment: Technically, it answers the question but I don't think it's what the user wanted. Passing an uninitialised pointer to `GetWindowRect` is a call for trouble.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can just type this inside your CWnd dialog:

```
CRect rect;
this->GetWindowRect( &rect );
```

Comment: The answer does not provide additional context to what is `CRect` or even `this->GetWindowRect`. I assume it refers to MFC but it doesn't answer the original question.